# Obtener valor de un Picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Tengo una aplicación móvil en react native, donde tengo un Picker de Vehículo, realizo la consulta respectiva en el fetch donde obtengo los vehículos de la base de datos, y tengo un botón que manda a llamar una función para obtener el Id del vehículo seleccionado y efectivamente lo muestra en un alert. Cuando realizo un alert en componentDidMount, el this.state.PickerVehiculo me lo muestra como vació, 
¿Como puedo obtener dinamicamente el valor del Picker en la funcion de componentDidMount? ¿Se podrá desde el Constructor? Esto lo necesito para pasar como parámetro en una URL de un fetch. Muchas gracias.

Este es mi código del fetch donde mando el parámetro respectivo del Picker

```
 alert(this.state.PickerVehiculo);
    fetch(`http://adress/api/InventarioMarchamos/obtenerSelectMarchamosCarga/${this.state.PickerVehiculo}`)
```

Constructor: 
 constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);

```
this.state = { 

 PickerVehiculo:''
   }
}
```

Picker:

```
        <Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.PickerVehiculo}
   onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({PickerVehiculo: itemValue})} >
    { this.state.dataSource.map((item, key)=>(
     <Picker.Item label={item.Placa} value={item.IdUnidad} key={key}   />)
     )}
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount()` se ejecuta después de `render()` durante el montaje del componente. Cuando se ejecuta, si recuperas el valor del *state*  *PickerVehiculo* al que asignaste un valor vacío en el *contructor* esto es lo que recuperas.
En la [doc de React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker) tienes este ejemplo de implementación:

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  style={{height: 50, width: 100}}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
    this.setState({language: itemValue})
  }>
  <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

Si modificas el estado del componente vuelve a ejecutarse el `render()` seguido de `componentWillUpdate()` (que reemplazaría a `componentDidMount()`), ahora deberías poder recuperar la ID seleccionada en este método. En tu caso `setState()` asignaría la ID seleccionada.
En el atributo *value* de cada `<Picker.Item/>` pon la ID del vehículo, y para recogerlo en el evento:

```
onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
    this.setState({
        PickerVehiculo: itemValue
    })
}
```